# Bootstrap 4 tabs not wrapping

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

**Problem happens in alpha 6 but not alpha 5**

In bootstrap 3 tabs would wrap onto the next line so they could be used on smaller screen sizes.

In Bootstrap 4 they don't wrap and poke off the side of the screen.  This is example from the Bootstrap 4 documentation.

How do i make it wrap like in bootstrap 3?

```css
#viewport
{
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="viewport">
<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#messages" role="tab">Messages</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#settings" role="tab">Settings</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home" role="tabpanel">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile" role="tabpanel">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages" role="tabpanel">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings" role="tabpanel">...</div>
</div>

</div>
```

(black outline shows small viewport.  On previous version the tabs would wrap to new line so all would be visible inside the black line)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nav tabs, like other components are now flexbox. Just use `flex-wrap`.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs flex-wrap" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab">Profile</a>
        </li>
        ...
</ul>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/hGPyyOv76W

I don't think it's an "issue", but rather "by design".

Another, maybe more responsive, approach would be to use `flex-column`, but only on `xs` widths. This way is stacks vertically instead of wrapping.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs flex-column flex-md-row" role="tablist">
         <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab">Home</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab">Profile</a>
         </li>
         ...
</ul>
```

[Demo](https://www.codeply.com/go/hGPyyOv76W)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an issue specific to the version of Bootstrap 4 you are using:

```css
#viewport
{
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="viewport">
<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#messages">Messages</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#settings">Settings</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home" role="tabpanel">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile" role="tabpanel">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages" role="tabpanel">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings" role="tabpanel">...</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I used the version on the bootstrap website.  Weird this happens.

Comment: It's still in Alpha, so there are bound to be some issues here and there

Comment: Yeah, I reported on their github page.  I'll use this version from now on.

Answer (score 0):

For Bootstart 4.1.3 don't forget to include popper.js e.g.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
```

At the moment the W3school [example](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_nav_tabs&stacked=h) is missing the aria-controls. This example worked for me:

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Navigation Tabs</h2>
  <p>Turn the nav menu into navigation tabs with the .nav nav-tabs class. Add the active class to the active/current link. If you want the tabs to be togglable, see the last example on the tutorial page.</p>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="homes-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#homes" role="tab" aria-controls="homes" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="profiles-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profiles" role="tab" aria-controls="profiles" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="contacts-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contacts" role="tab" aria-controls="contacts" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="homes" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="homes-tab">home</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profiles" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profiles-tab">profile</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contacts" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contacts-tab">contact</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add popper.js, the id and the aria-controls as [documented](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/#js) it seems to work:

```css
#viewport
{
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="viewport">
<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="profiles-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="messages-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#messages" role="tab" aria-controls="messages" aria-selected="false">Messages</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="settings-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#settings" role="tab" aria-controls="settings" aria-selected="false">Settings</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">home</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">profile</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="messages-tab">messages</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="settings-tab">settings</div>
</div>

</div>
```